# Writing/reading to paths with interleaved double dots fails on iOS 8

Tags: ios8, nsdata

This code fails on iOS 8, although it would work on iOS 7

```
UIImage *imageTest = ...

NSString *file = @"../Documents/Test.png";
NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: file];

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageTest) writeToFile: fullpath atomically: YES];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: file];
```

On iOS 8 I need to use this instead

```
NSString *file = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.png"];

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageTest) writeToFile:file atomically:YES];

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: file];
```

...but then I have to refactor my project and a third party library that works with paths relative to the main bundle.

It seems to me that paths like `"/PathToMainBundle/MyApp.app/../Documents/something"` are either not properly resolved, or not allowed at all by iOS 8

That path should be the same as `"/PathToMainBundle/Documents/something"`

Comment: This worked for me up to iOS8:   `NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SomeFile" ofType:@"pdf"];` Now I can't even see the file in the app bundle.

Comment: @Jorgen  but I need to create the file first using paths relative to the main bundle because of the library I'm using

Comment: As I said. With iOS8 I can't even see the file when looking on my device with iExplorer or the Devices window in Xcode 6. Totally confused.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS8, Resource Directory(App.app), Data Directory(NSCachesDirectory, NSTemporaryDirectory,..) are managed separately as below.

- iOS7 Directory Hierarchy

  - App UUID

    - Documents
    - Library

      - Caches
      - Preferences
    - tmp
    - App.app
- iOS8 Directory Hierarchy

  - Resource Directory UUID

    - App.app
  - Data Directory UUID

    - Documents
    - Library

      - Caches
      - Preferences
    - tmp

So, you should fix code based on absolute path in iOS8.

```
UIImage *imageTest = ...

NSString *fullpath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.png"];

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageTest) writeToFile: fullpath atomically: YES];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: fullpath];
```