# AVAudioRecorder.record() always returns "false" in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying to create a practice app using AVAudioRecorder that, upon pressing a button, records 1 second of audio through the iPhone's mic to a file called "Test.wav" and plays it back. However, both the record() and recordForDuration() methods both seem to fail every time I try to execute them. I've already tried setting up an AVAudioSession and making it active, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
```

import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var recordAndPlayButton: UIButton!

let settings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    AVSampleRateKey: 192000.0,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
    AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
    AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false
]

var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
var recorder : AVAudioRecorder!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)
    audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)

    recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Test", ofType: "wav")!), settings: settings, error: nil)
    recorder.delegate = self
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func recordSoundAndPlay() {
    recorder.prepareToRecord()
    println(recorder.recordForDuration(1.0))

    var testSound = SystemSoundID()
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Test", ofType: "wav")!), &testSound)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(testSound)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too - turns out it's not actually to do with AVAudioRecorder but actually the way user directories are structured in iOS8. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989767/writing-reading-to-paths-with-interleaved-double-dots-fails-on-ios-8) question and answer for more info.

Anyway, I fixed it by changing the way the file was accessed to something more like this:

```
let DOCUMENTS_FOLDER: NSString! = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).first as NSString

@IBAction func recordSoundAndPlay() {
    recorder.prepareToRecord()
    println(recorder.recordForDuration(1.0))

    var testSound = SystemSoundID()
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(DOCUMENTS_FOLDER)/Test.wav")), &testSound)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(testSound)
}
```

Let me know how it goes!