# Cannot writeToFile toFullPath in iOS 8 issue

Tags: ios, ios8, writetofile

I have an issue that I cannot save in iOS 8 while it is working fine in iOS 7. Please where would be my issue?

```
.h       
    NSMutableArray *selected;


.m
    - (void)saveSelected
    {
        if (![selected writeToFile:[SettingVO toFullPath:@"selected"] atomically:YES])
        {
            NSLog(@"Could not save selected!!! %@", selectedParitems);
        }
    }
```

Update: I have include `toFullPath` method and I debugged it. I found that with iOS 7 it is not passing throw if `fileMgr` and working fine while with iOS 8 it returns nil. I hope this helps.

```
+ (NSString *)toFullPath:(NSString *)path
{
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundlePath];
    NSMutableArray *components = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[url pathComponents]];
    [components removeLastObject];
    [components addObject:@"Documents"];
    [components addObject:@"data"];

    NSString *fullPath = [NSString pathWithComponents:components];

    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ( ![fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:NULL] )
    {
        if ([fileMgr createDirectoryAtPath:fullPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil])
        {
            //--N-SLog(@"+ Items directory created.");
        }
        else
        {
            //--N-SLog(@"- Couldn't create Items directory!!!");
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return [fullPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
}
```

Comment: What is returned by `[SettingVO toFullPath:@"selected"]`?

Comment: In iOS 8 it returns `NULL` but in iOS 7 it returns "/Users/CANCAN/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BD971C52-6E84-4DDA-A90F-588476CFA2D1/data/Applications/D5E87B2C-C027-4F53-88B1-6FFF989CD5D8/Documents/data/selected" which a path @PhillipMills

Comment: You may have use the debugger inside `toFullPath:` to find out why it returns NULL.

Comment: @PhillipMills I have updated my question I hope it can help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989767/writing-reading-to-paths-with-interleaved-double-dots-fails-on-ios-8/26718827#26718827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the bundle path if you want to find a writable location.  That points to the application, which is read-only.

Use...

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths firstObject];
if (path) {
    //  ...
}
```

...to get the base document path.